# Why do most application protocols have two ports assigned?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, ports

So I am trying to learn about the application layer in the OSI model and when I go to the IANA website, I notice that most of the well known protocols have same port assigned for TCP and UDP.

For example, HTTP is a well known protocol I know it uses the TCP port 80, but the IANA website lists port 80 on UDP as well. Same is the case with other famous protocols like DNS, SMTP etc.,

Does this mean that all these protocols use both TCP and UDP? If that is the case, can someone tell me in what cases the HTTP protocol uses TCP and UDP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocols that have registered both the TCP and UDP versions of a certain port do so because they either use both transport protocols at least in some cases, or because at some point someone proposed a protocol addition that would use the other transport, but possibly that proposal never got widely deployed, but there was no reason to bother un-registering the other transport's port. The reasons vary by protocol.

HTTP traditionally uses port 80/TCP, but now QUIC (HTTP/3) uses 80/UDP (or 443/UDP).

DNS has traditionally used 53/UDP, but falls back to 53/TCP in some cases, like if the answer message is too large for a single UDP packet, or for "zone transfers", where one DNS server downloads all the DNS records for a whole domain in order to act as a secondary DNS server for that domain. There is also some interest in securing DNS by doing DNS over TLS (DoT), which would be over TCP, not DTLS over UDP. However, it seems that DNS over HTTPS (DoH) has gained more traction than DoT.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, this really clears things up for me. So if someone asks me what protocol HTTP/DNS uses would it be right to say TCP/UDP respectively or should I say depending on what the HTTP request or DNS request is?

Comment: If you can only choose one, say the main one the protocol is known for using. If it's a job interview, say, "Well, it mainly/traditionally uses ___, but in the following situations it uses ___.…"